# OnMouseOver controls are painted in a light red color and remain in this state?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, styles

**You need at least 10 reputation to post images**

[GIF imge problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Z9P.gif)

I do not even know how to solve this problem.

github   Veselov-Dmitry/DP

**UPD:**

here's the video, if you think I'm doing it through style, thanks for the compliment

https://youtu.be/ywK3_twnJsk

**UPD:UPD:**

1) downloaded and installed the latest update for MSVS2017 proffessional

2) I use the video card nvidia gt670. I downloaded the latest driver update and installed it.

Problems of the reser.

Comment: On StackOverflow we care about high quality questions and answers. 
Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask a question again. Your problem should be understandable by reading the **text** in your post. You may use images to enhance your post.

Comment: thanks, i will try to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) downloaded and installed the latest update for MS VS 2017 professional

2) I use the video card nvidia gt670. I downloaded the latest driver update and installed it.

Problems of the reser.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to edit the background, we could edit the template, we could right click the Button like the following screen shot:

[image]

You would get the XAML for the button like:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}""/>

</Grid>
```

So you would check the style like mine "Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}"" for this Button, and then just edit it in your side directly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is not this, I added a video

Comment: @ДмитрийТДА, Do you test it in other Windows 10 environment, actually we have to make sure that whether it is related to the project itself or the windows like the color/resolution or display connection in your machine.

Comment: @  Дмитрий ТДА, What about this issue in your side? Would you please share the latest information in your side, it still no help, could you share a simple sample using one drive? I will debug it in our side using the same Environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. but the transition to Windows 7 did not help
I tried on Windows 7, saved the project and moved it to Windows 10, but the red spots remained. Then I just updated the development environment and the video card driver

Comment: @ Дмитрий ТДА,No sample is hard for us to repro it, since it works well in window 7, but your windows 10 has this issue, do you test it in other Windows 10 machines? We have to make sure that whether it is related to your Windows Environment, as you also add the "debugging" tag, not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result? Actually I feel that it was not the debugging tool or the project's issue, we would think about the Windows 10 in your side. Of course, if possible, just create a simple WPF app in your windows 10, view the result again.

Comment: @Дмитрий ТДА, What about this issue? Do you find the real reason in your side?

Comment: I could not repeat this problem any more. Problem solved when I reinstalled the video driver. When there was a problem, it was only when creating WPF applications, for example, on WinForms this did not happen

Comment: @Дмитрий ТДА, If issue has been resolved after you reinstalled the video driver, you could post it as the answer and mark it. But if it has other issue, it would be better if yo could open a new case, so we don't have to view the previous discussions. Any issues, feel free to share it.

Answer (score 0):

in the style

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonC" TargetType="Button" >
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value=""/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                **<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>**
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This trigger was not when the problem hit. I added it to remove the problem. I specifically indicated "blue" but it did not help.

Comment: yes, sorry. I compile your code on my machine and it works...no mouve red effectfs...seems linked to your env. you are under win10 ? me on 7

Comment: try to remove style on one button <Button Style ="x:null" />

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is not this, I added a video

Comment: as i told, it works fine for me on Windows 7 !  you are using Windows 10 and some special tools ?

Comment: I'm using a clean install, no tools

Comment: then it's windows 10 ?? can you try it on another machine ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. but the transition to Windows 7 did not help I tried on Windows 7, saved the project and moved it to Windows 10, but the red spots remained. Then I just updated the development environment and the video card driver

Comment: does it work on your windows 7ven ? because, me yes...I don't know what to say more to help you :-(

Comment: on Windows 7 the project works. I tried to save it (on Windows 7) and after saving again open on Windows 10